# how to ignore class prefix in css file

Tags: css, sass

I see some e.g. div/button style in Chrome console like this:

```
/* Chrome browser styles tab */
.ItemClass1-0-3-171.ItemClass2-0-3-173: {
    background-color: "red"
}
```

How do I define a new style in CSS ignoring that class numbers? because it can be a different number for other div/button on the page..

```
/* CSS file */
.ItemClass1.ItemClass2 {
    background-color: "blue"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two [attribute contains selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) for this.

```css
[class*="ItemClass1"][class*="ItemClass2"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="ItemClass1-0-3-171 ItemClass2-0-3-173">foo</p>
```

But keep in mind that this will also select elements with the class `fooItemClass2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with a [starts-with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#syntax) value to pick up anything that starts with `ItemClass`.

Note: This solution assumes ItemClass is the *first* classname and doesn't account for whether the element has both classes. For these reasons [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67942522/636077) might better suit your needs.

```css
[class^='ItemClass'] {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="ItemClass1-0-3-171.ItemClass2-0-3-173"></div>
```

Comment: I think the `.` was intended to select an element with both classes, or not?

Comment: Could be. If so, your answer is probably better. (And my solution assumes ItemClass is the _first_ classname, so your answer is arguably better either way.)